# How to suppress Table of Contents section numbers?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I am using the following to suppress the numbering of `\section`s:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{}
\makeatother
```

But in my `\tableofcontents`, the section numbers still appear. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: do you want section numbers suppressed everywhere, or only in the toc?  (if everywhere, david's answer is good.  if toc only, things get a bit more complicated.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't do that, instead do

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

this counter controls the level at which LaTeX numbers headings.

Comment: @David Carlisle, I implemented this with success as well. However, beside *each* section title in the body of the text, "0." appears. Is there any way to remove this?